# How can I get a log of all commits a month after/before a tag?

Tags: git, git-log

I am looking for a command using `git log` in a way similar to

```
git log --pretty=oneline tag1...tag2
```

but I'd like to get a log of all the commits a month *after* a given tag, without having to explicitly specify the date of the tag in question. Something like

```
git log --pretty=oneline tag1...(1 month)
```

Same question for all commits one month *before* a given tag.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not strictly speaking possible.  If you are using annotated tags, and you only care about when a commit was made, not when it was pushed, then you could come up with something that may work for your purposes.

Comment: I have annotated tags and I just care about the commit not when it was pushed.

Comment: So your annotated Tag has a date in it (git cat-file -p $TAG) to see it.  Adjust the number to offset by +/-30 days, then use either --after or --before in conjunction with the tag itself.

Comment: I don't have any date with this command : git cat-file -p $TAG ...

Comment: It's the weird string of numbers like "1409513798 -0700".  You can also use `git show --pretty=` and ask for just the date.

Comment: Thank you, I started a new project if someone is interested. https://github.com/tbille/gitProjectAnalyser